# Request in controller constructor Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, constructor, controller, request, middleware

I'm really desperate.
I'm migrating a laravel project from 5.2 to 5.5 and it's all going to perfection. But I'm having problem to use a Request object in controller constructor. It seems that the controllers skip the middleware if I use Request object.
I tried to use $this->middleware('api'); but not working.

```
public function __construct(Request $req) {
    $this->commerce = new Commerce($req->user->currency()->currency);
}
```

My 'api' middleware push user object in the request.
In construct method $req->user is null!

The api routes are correctly set and the other controllers working!

What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Request object in controller in a callback function in the `$this->middleware()` method. Try this:

```
public function __construct(){
  $this->middleware(function($req, $next){
    $this->commerce = new Commerce($req->user->currency()->currency);

    return $next($req);
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried same method but with the middleware code... not working!

Comment: Shouldn't your `return $next($request)` be `return $next($req)`?